# PyQT How to build UI according to List?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm currently very confused on dealing with signals in building widgets in a PyQT application from a list parameter.

All I want is given a list (or a number of the size of a list) and build that many buttons in my application, each of which changes a data element within a list, which is an instance variable.

The problem is that I only know how to deal with signals when I have explicit functions, which can only be built statically and not dynamically from runtime, or as far as I know of.

Does anybody have a solution? I need to form an arbitrary set of buttons based upon an argument that will allow changing members of a list, which is the same size of the argument provided.

I tried using a lambda function, but variable assignment isn't allowed in a lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically create a function while creating your buttons, and connecting signals to this function:

```
from PyQt4 import Qt, QtGui, QtCore

app=QtGui.QApplication([])
w=QtGui.QWidget()
QtGui.QVBoxLayout(w)

buttons = []
for i in range(5):
    new_button = QtGui.QPushButton("click me %d" % i, w)
    w.layout().addWidget(new_button)

    # here is the dynamically created function
    # use keyword arguments to keep track of the button
    # or any other variable
    def button_clicked(button=new_button):
        print "User clicked on", button.text()
    QtCore.QObject.connect(new_button, Qt.SIGNAL("clicked()"), button_clicked)

w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: What would be the version of this if you wanted a set of LineEdits rather than buttons?

Comment: Just replace QPushButton by QLineEdit... The signal will also have to be changed (returnPressed? textChanged? whatever). And finally you code the behaviour you want in the callback function.